# XIB hangs a lot, Changing View As Device fixes

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, xcode8

I made a project on `Xcode 7.3`, but after the release of `xcode 8` I had to move onto that as I upgraded my project from `swift 2.2` to `swift 2.3` too, but im having a very weird problem. When I open my XIB file, it makes `xcode` very very slow almost crawling, I got 3 ways to fix the problem,

1) Take a new View from toolbar and make the previous view the subview of new view and apply contraints and it will stop hanging.

2) View the xib as source code, insert random spaces at the end of lines (Let xcode know that you edited file whatever it is), save it and come back, it will occasionally fix the problem but didnt work everytime.

3) when XIB is hanging, change the device in View as and it will start working properly untill you go to another XIB and come back.

This is happening in Xcode 8.1, does anyone know what can be the issue ?